# Property 'navigate' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRoute'

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I'm trying to navigate to listProfiles component through profile component (The previous component). I'm using an `ActivatedRoute` and trying to navigate to it through `this.router.navigate(['/listProfiles`])

Code in the component that should navigate to listProfile component

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute){}

deleteProfile():void{
   this.router.navigate(['/listProfiles']); //Gives the error message in the title
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { ListProfilesComponent } from './list-profiles/list-profiles.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'addProfile', component: AddProfileComponent },
{ path: 'listProfiles', component: ListProfilesComponent},
{ path: 'profile/:id', component: ProfileComponent},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ListProfilesComponent,
  ProfileComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  NoopAnimationsModule,
  BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes,
    {enableTracing: true}
    )
  ],
  providers: [ StorageService, LoginService, ClientIDService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Error is correct, you should use `Router` instead of `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: Ye, thats it! Sorry for the simple mistake

Comment: happens to all of us ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you have to add :

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }
```

then :

```
 this.router.navigate(...
```

Comment: Oh ok, simple mistake, Will set as answer in a few minutes

Comment: Because I can't do that unless the post has been up for 15 min. As I said, I will submit it as an answer in a few minutes

Comment: @Nawrez I already described, but get's the same error.Please help.

Comment: Angular 14 same error! Solved with this